# Paypal Payment Standard Order data not recieve when payment success

Tags: php, magento

I upgrade mageto version 1.5 to 1.9.
In that when i do payment with paypal standard than payment successfully complete but order status 'Payment Pending' Display.
And in Order detail not get any paypal payment transaction detail.
Help me for that.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some times it will become completed in 2-3 days once it receives more details from customer. Paypal will generate IPN again. search for reason_code below for possible reasons for pending:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id08CTB0S055Z

Comment: So what to do to solve this problem can you please give me more explanation?